# Azure YAML Pipeline Configure Environments for Snowflake CICD SchemaChange

Tags: azure-devops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-pipelines-yaml

I currently have a working Azure Yaml Pipeline that uses Snowflake's [SchemaChange](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange) but need to add a deployment job that references a pipeline environment within the yaml steps to enforce an approval of the pipeline.  The YAML pipeline works without the deployment job in the step.  But when I move the code into the deployment job it seems to lose reference to the correct file location for `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` and gives an "Invalid root folder" error when executed.

If I remove the schemachange parameter **-f $(PROJECT_FOLDER)/migrations** from the code, the pipeline successfully runs and requires the environment approval that I expect. But `SchemaChange` does not actually execute against the changed files because it isn't looking at the /migrations path that my code lives in.  This seems to show the `yaml` pipeline and environment are setup correctly but something is not working with the pipeline variable `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` within the job deployment step.

I could use some help understanding why the pipeline variable is no longer working and what I am missing to get this working. Here's the working `YAML` pipeline code:

```yaml
    # Deploy database changes using schemachange
    # https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange
    # (see https://aka.ms/yaml for the YAML schema reference)
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - development
      paths:
        include:
        - /migrations
    
    stages:
    - stage: 'dev_stage'
      displayName: 'Dev Stage'
      variables:
      - group: Snowflake_Variables_Dev
      - name: env
        value: "Dev"
      jobs:
      - job: 'build_job'
        displayName: 'Snowflake Dev'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
          displayName: 'Use Python 3.8.x'
          inputs:
            versionSpec: '3.8.x'
        - task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              echo 'Starting bash task'
              echo "PROJECT_FOLDER $(PROJECT_FOLDER)"
              python --version
              echo 'Step 1: Installing schemachange'
              pip install schemachange --upgrade
              echo 'Step 2: Running schemachange'
              schemachange -f $(PROJECT_FOLDER)/migrations -a $(SF_ACCOUNT) -u $(SF_USERNAME) -r $(SF_ROLE) -w $(SF_WAREHOUSE) -d $(SF_DATABASE) -c $(SF_DATABASE).DEVOPS_CONTROL.CHANGE_HISTORY --config-folder $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/schemachangeconfigs/development --create-change-history-table
          env:
            SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: $(SF_PASSWORD)
```

Here's where it stops working.  I add in a deployment job to the step and the pipeline variable $(PROJECT_FOLDER) which has a value of $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) no longer works.
**Code with Error**:

```yaml
    # Deploy database changes using schemachange
    # https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange
    # (see https://aka.ms/yaml for the YAML schema reference)
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - development
      paths:
        include:
        - /migrations
    
    stages:
    - stage: 'dev_stage'
      variables:
        - group: Snowflake_Variables_Dev
        - name: env
          value: "dev"
      jobs:
      - deployment: DeployStage
        displayName: 'Dev Stage Test'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        environment: 
          name: 'Snowflake_Development'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - task: UsePythonVersion@0
                displayName: 'Use Python 3.8.x'
                inputs:
                  versionSpec: '3.8.x'
              - task: Bash@3
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    echo 'Starting bash task'
                    echo "PROJECT_FOLDER $(PROJECT_FOLDER)"
                    echo "System DefaultWorkingDirectory $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
                    python --version
                    echo 'Step 1: Installing schemachange'
                    pip install schemachange --upgrade
                    echo 'Step 2: Running schemachange'
                    schemachange -f $(PROJECT_FOLDER)/migrations -a $(SF_ACCOUNT) -u $(SF_USERNAME) -r $(SF_ROLE) -w $(SF_WAREHOUSE) -d $(SF_DATABASE) -c $(SF_DATABASE).DEVOPS_CONTROL.CHANGE_HISTORY --config-folder $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/schemachangeconfigs/development --create-change-history-table
                env:
                  SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: $(SF_PASSWORD)
```

When the pipeline runs it installs schemachange and then gives the following error:

```bash
    Step 2: Running schemachange
    schemachange version: 3.6.1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/bin/schemachange", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schemachange/cli.py", line 868, in main
        config = get_schemachange_config(**schemachange_args)
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schemachange/cli.py", line 673, in get_schemachange_config
        raise ValueError(_err_invalid_folder.format(folder_type='root', path=config['root_folder']))
    **ValueError: Invalid root folder: /home/vsts/work/1/s/migrations**
    ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` was empty.
[image]

Unlike a [tradition job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops),

> A [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) doesn't automatically clone the source repo. You can checkout the source repo within your job with `checkout: self`.

With the`checkout` step at the very beginning of all tasks to download your code from repo into the `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` on the agent, you may then use `tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` command to check if the required files are there. Here is sample `steps` section.

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.8.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.8.x'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo 'Starting bash task'
      echo "PROJECT_FOLDER $(PROJECT_FOLDER)"
      echo "System DefaultWorkingDirectory $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
      tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      python --version
      echo 'Step 1: Installing schemachange'
      pip install schemachange --upgrade
      echo 'Step 2: Running schemachange'
      schemachange -f $(PROJECT_FOLDER)/migrations -a $(SF_ACCOUNT) -u $(SF_USERNAME) -r $(SF_ROLE) -w $(SF_WAREHOUSE) -d $(SF_DATABASE) -c $(SF_DATABASE).DEVOPS_CONTROL.CHANGE_HISTORY --config-folder $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/schemachangeconfigs/development --create-change-history-table
  env:
    SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: $(SF_PASSWORD)
```

Hope the information can help.